# Different ID in every shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to make an Instagram-box on the author profile of my page. I need every profile to be different, and to do that I need to change the ID in my Instagram Widget-shortcode on every page. The shortcode for the widget is:

```
[instagram-feed id="" imageres="full" showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]
```

To change the id on every page I have used the_author_meta('instagram');. The idea was to do this:

```
echo do shortcode( '[instagram-feed id="<?php the_author_meta('user_email') ?>" imageres="full"  showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]');
```

But it wont generate because it's PHP inside a shortcode. I have also tried this:

```
    echo ( '[instagram-feed id="' ); 
    the_author_meta('instagram');
    echo ( '" imageres="full" showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]' );
```

which generated the code correctly with a different ID on every profile:

```
[instagram-feed id="1427468000 (and something different on other profile)" imageres="full" showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]
```

But now it will now only display as text, not be the result of the code. Anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: What if you concatenate the string, like   `$author_ig = '[instagram-feed id="' . get_the_author_meta('instagram') . '"  imageres="full" showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]';   
echo do_shortcode($author_ig); `

Comment: The above comment will do the trick. You must use do_shortcode() if you're inserting the shortcode in the template rather than in an editor.

Comment: @czerspalace Can you add your comment as answer? Thanks!

Comment: @ialocin yes, will do!

Comment: Perfect, now Luca can accept it. @czerspalace

Answer (score 1):

What if you concatenate the string, like

```
$author_ig = '[instagram-feed id="' . get_the_author_meta('instagram') . '"  imageres="full" showheader="true" showbutton="true" buttoncolor="#fff" buttontextcolor="#000" showfollow="false"]';    
echo do_shortcode($author_ig);
```

I used `get_the_author_meta` instead of `the_author_meta`, because the former returns the meta as a string while the latter echo's the meta.